# angularjs ng-model fails with variable name binding when value does not exists with plnkr

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have to create a form in which meta data is coming from server . So I can not use hard code variable binding. Say I have a column definition studentcol that has an expression and display name.

$scope.studentcol = {expression:"studentid","display":"name"}
$scope.data = {};

If I use . It get failed. It will work properly either I use hard code expression say data.studentid.display or value for studentid already exists in data then above binding works well

http://plnkr.co/edit/YBt37TuILz1KsPOUAo9q?p=preview

Please suggest

Rohit Bansal

Comment: Not a trivial task. Binding are compiled before the actual angular template is rendered. What you are asking is for support for dynamic binding expression change. You need to $compile service for this. See if the documentation on $compile and the sample provided is of any help. http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$compile

Comment: Thanks Chandermani, But making directive is not a solution for this.